# Differences between Mann-Whitney U and chi-square tests for if two-samples come from same distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference, nonparametric

In a textbook, it introduces the chi-square goodness of fit test to test independence between two variables (organized in a contingency table), which can also be used to test if m samples are likely to come from the same distribution by using one dimension as samples and the other as values/bins.

Then in another chapter, it introduces the Mann-Whitney test, which seems to do the same thing. Both are nonparametric and chisquare can be applied to continuous distribution by discretizing the bins.

I am confused that they seem to do the same thing, so for the purpose of testing if two populations are the same (distribution and parameters), what're their differences?

Comment: which can also be used to test if m samples are likely to come from the same distribution by using one dimension as samples and the other as values/bins. please elaborate!

Comment: my bad, say values [-5, -3] [-3 -1] [-1 1] [1 3]...as bins (X) and samples 1 2 3...m as Y in a contingency table, then we can test if all m samples are likely from the same distribution as if testing for indifference between X and Y. Then in a later chapter, I read the Mann-Whitney test which seems to do the same thing for 2 samples, hence my question.

Comment: I found the following! https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Wall2/Wal4_3.html

Comment: Mann-Whitney test, which seems to do the same thing. what do you mean?

Comment: if two populations are the same (distribution and parameters), what're their differences ? could you post a glimpse of your data ?

Answer (score 4):

The Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney two-sample rank sum test tests whether observations from one group tend to be bigger than observations from another group.  It is used for ordinal or continuous response variables Y and not for the case where Y is binary or represents unordered categories.  But if Y were binary the p-value from the Wilcoxon test, though not very accurate, would not be far from the p-value from a $2\times 2 \chi^{2}$ Pearson test.  The same is true when doing a two-sample $t$-test on binary Y.  So tests of association have a strong relationship to tests of group differences.

The one-sample $\chi^2$ goodness of fit test is altogether different.  It measures the distance between observed category frequencies and the theoretical frequencies that would be observed had Y come from a specific parametric distribution.

Comment: What you say seems to be in-line with https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Wall2/Wal4_3.html. Right?